# Java pojo setter return type is int but getter return type is string

Tags: java, spring

I am creating an API,

My controller is

```java
public EmployeeResponse(@RequestBody EmployeeRequest reqPacket) { }
```

My pojo class is

```
EmployeeRequest {
    int age;
    String name;
}
```

So basically my `getAge()` and and `setAge()` methods shall be dealing with int type only

Now, if my request packet is

```json
{
    "name": "smith"
}
```

Means age parameter is not there in request packet

So in my controller it shall be by default set by zero (because type is int)

But I want to know if i got age field in request packet or not.

What is best solution for this?

I can't even use `@NotNull` annotation.. because default value is zero for int type.. so it won't work..

Can I make getter type as string and setter type again as int?

Comment: Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: @aled, I don't think there is an error or any log to mention. OP has asked a real simple question

Comment: There is code, small as it may be. Formatting makes it easier to read the question.

Comment: Yes @aled, I totally agree with the formatting part :)

Comment: If you want to distinguish between `null` and `0`, you could just use `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: Please format your code in your questions, regardless how small. This'll make it way better readable. This time I fix the formatting for you.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to change field age to type Integer. If no paramater passed, it will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a default constructor

```
EmployeeRequest(String name){
this.name = name;
this.age = 0;
}
```

Comment: kiese, still i will get zero value, so my @NotNull validation won't work brother.